# How to change tab position sorting order from admin catalog product Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, tabs

Need to change sorting order up/down tab product add/edit from admin catalog product.

[image]

Comment: you mean to say short description attribute position would like to change?

Comment: No, Product Reviews, Customizable Option, Product in Website etc...

Answer (score 5):

One of the possible solution to sort these `Groups`, you need to go to `Stores -> Attribute Set` in admin panel.

Click the `attribute set` which is set right now on the `product` which you are checking. It may be like this

[image]

Now `Drag & Drop` the Group which you want to sort in whatever position.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: want to change position "Product Review, Customizable option, Product in Website" etc..

Comment: Whatever you made changes in your attribute set it will reflect on product page like  in above example if you want to change `Gift option` group to above  `Design` group you just need to drag and drop the gift option to above design so it is change of position of Gift option group except some of the specific group which are not the part of Attribute set